# Installing mapserver in cygwin with regex.c

Tags: mapserver, regular-expression, cygwin

This is my first time installing mapserver in cygwin, but I am an experienced user of both cygwin and mapserver.

The thing is that I'm getting a regex issue after doing cmake in the build directory inside the mapserver-6.4.1 directory (after doing tar -zxvf mapserver-6.4.1.tar.gz, etc, etc). My cygwin installation meets all the requirements afaik to build mapserver. I'm not sure, though, if regex.h is causing a problem. This is what I get after running cmake:

```
--
Gery@gery /opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1/build
$ cmake .. -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=1 -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=1 -DWITH_SOS=1 -DWITH_KML=1 -DWITH_PHP=1 -DWITH_PERL=1 -DWITH_PYTHON=1 -DWITH_GD=1 -DWITH_GDAL=1 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/gdal/gdal-1.11.0" -DWITH_OGR=1 -DWITH_PROJ=1 -DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1 -DWITH_ICONV=0 -DWITH_EXEMPI=0 -DWITH_MYSQL=0
-- Defining WIN32 under Cygwin due to CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32
-- /usr/include/php/main
-- Found PHP5-Version 5.5.16 (using /usr/bin/php-config)
-- * Summary of configured options for this build
--  * Mandatory components
--   * png: /usr/lib/libpng.dll.a
--   * jpeg: /usr/lib/libjpeg.dll.a
--   * freetype: /usr/lib/libfreetype.dll.a
--  * Optional components
--   * GDAL: /opt/gdal/gdal-1.11.0/libgdal.a
--   * OGR: /opt/gdal/gdal-1.11.0/libgdal.a
--   * GD: /usr/lib/libgd.dll.a
--   * GIF: /usr/lib/libgif.dll.a
--   * MYSQL: disabled
--   * FRIBIDI: /usr/lib/libfribidi.dll.a
--   * GIF: /usr/lib/libgif.dll.a
--   * CAIRO: /usr/lib/libcairo.dll.a
--   * SVGCAIRO: disabled
--   * RSVG: disabled
--   * CURL: /usr/lib/libcurl.dll.a
--   * PROJ: /usr/lib/libproj.dll.a
--   * LIBXML2: /usr/lib/libxml2.dll.a
--   * POSTGIS: /usr/lib/libpq.a
--   * GEOS: /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dll.a
--   * FastCGI: /usr/lib/libfcgi.dll.a
--   * Oracle Spatial: disabled
--   * SDE: disabled
--   * Exempi XMP: disabled
--  * Optional features
--   * WMS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * WFS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * WCS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * SOS SERVER: ENABLED
--   * WMS CLIENT: ENABLED
--   * WFS CLIENT: ENABLED
--   * ICONV: disabled
--   * Thread-safety support: disabled
--   * KML output: ENABLED
--   * Z+M point coordinate support: disabled
--   * XML Mapfile support: disabled
--  * Mapscripts
--   * Python: ENABLED
--   * PHP: ENABLED
--   * PERL: ENABLED
--   * RUBY: disabled
--   * JAVA: disabled
--   * C#: disabled
--   * Apache Module (Experimental): disabled
--
-- Will install files to /usr/local
-- Will install libraries to /usr/local/lib
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:233 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    //regex.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx

-- Build files have been written to: /opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1/build

Gery@gery /opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1/build
$
--
```

then it stops. make and make install do nothing, just a "stop" message appears:

```
--
Gery@gery /opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1/build
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Gery@gery /opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1/build
$ make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
--
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it basically was to change this:

```
-DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1
```

to

```
-DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0
```

so, I used:

```
cmake .. -DWITH_OGR=0 -DWITH_GDAL=0 -DWITH_WCS=0 -DWITH_WFS=0 -DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0
```

and Mapserver compiled flawlessly.